# counting a number of spaces in a list python

Tags: python, list, count

I am making a text based game, and you can place a ship piece off the game board (not a intended feature). I have been searching the web for a way to count 2 characters into a list and see if it is a certain character (so i can tell if someone placed off the board), but so far i have not found any solution. Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Use a for loop and check each character in the string one at a time.

Comment: Your question and your problem don't seem related at all. I have a really strong feeling that the way you're doing things probably isn't optimal.

Comment: I am using lists as my game board. I use a for loop to print the lists in a certain order. and when you place a piece it puts it in the list you specified.

Comment: You should really use `curses` for this kind of thing...

Answer (score 0):

It would be more helpful to have an example of what your list looks like, but here's one possible solution.

Assuming you have a list of X's and O's like so:

```
example_list = ['X', 'O', 'O', 'X']
```

Now:

```
# Check if the second character is 'O'
if example_list[1] == 'O':
    # Do something
else:
    # Do something else
```

*Note that this would work the same way with the string `"XOOX"`*, i.e.

```
>>> example_string = "ABCD"
>>> print example_string[1]
B
>>> example_string[1] == "B"
True
>>> example_string[1] == "X"
False
```

Comment: Additionally: 
If you want to **count** the appearances of a character in a list, you can use `count` (e.g. `list.count("X")`)

If you want to find out, where in the list a certain character is, use `index` (e.g. `x.index("X")` returns the **first** appearance of "x" in list)